# Multiple Return Type Syntax in Boo?

Tags: boo, method-signature, multiple-return-values

I'm trying to define a method in Boo which returns two things, but the compiler is spitting out the message:

> expecting "COLON", found ','.

Here's how I tried defining the method:

```
from System.Collections.Generic import HashSet

# ValueParameter is a class defined elsewhere.
def evaluate(s as string, limit as string) as double, HashSet[of ValueParameter]:
```

I've looked through the docs, and though I see examples of how to return multiple items, I don't see any examples where they declare the return type as returning multiple types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [the swap example on the wiki](https://github.com/bamboo/boo/wiki/Differences-with-Csharp), which declares a function that uses multiple return values, and ran it through the compiler with the `-p:boo` flag, which outputs a code representation of the final form of the AST after all the processing has been done.  It reports that the type of this function is `(int)`.  When you return two dissimilar types, such as your double and HashSet, the return type is `(object)`.

Comment: I found this out by intentionally setting the return type incorrectly (to `string`) and then having the contents of the function just be `return 12.3, HashSet[of ValueParameter]()` and the compiler spat out that it couldn't cast `(object)` to `string`. The next problem ended up being I couldn't find a way to then extract the `double`... I could get it out as an `object`, but it wouldn't let me cast it to a `double` because that's a `Value Type` or whatever. So I rethought the method and changed it to accept a `HashMap` which it modifies, and it returns only a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

You can import `Tuple` from `System` and use that to return a tuple with types:

```
import System

def string_and_int(s as string, i as int) as Tuple[of string, int]:
    return Tuple[of string, int](s, i)
```

This preserves the type for each element correctly. However be warned that in Boo, anyway, the Tuple type is not iterable or sliceable so you have to get it using `.Item1`, `.Item2` etc:

```
 example = string_and_int("s", 2)
 print example.Item1
 # 's'
 print example.Item2
 # 2
```